# What is the Ruby equivalent of the PHP substr()?

Tags: php, ruby, string

What is the Ruby equivalent of the PHP statement

`<?php echo substr("abcdefghijklm", 0, 5);  ?>`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the bracket notation, with the same two arguments as for `substr`.

```
substring = bigstring[0,5]
```

I used to recommend http://railsforphp.com/substr as a great way to find Ruby/Rails equivalents for common PHP functions, but apparently it's no longer online. That's unfortunate :/

Comment: Why? Nothing wrong with someone who knows PHP wanting to learn Ruby.

Comment: to be completely pedantic, you handled the substring but not the output... ;)   `<%= bigstring[0,5] %>`

Comment: Well, actually, it would be `<%= "abcdefghijklm"[0,5] %>` :)

Comment: @Nakilon: I don't know how its full lessons are, but it's fantastic for translating simple PHP functions.

Comment: `substring = bigstring[0..-5]` gives you the string minus the last 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`byteslice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-byteslice) method

```
"abcdefghijklm".byteslice(0, 5) => "abcde"
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-byteslice